# How to take existing list (single column) and add rows between each entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of 100 cities in column A and I'm trying to figure out how to take that list and duplicate each entry 3 additional times.  I tried to use Offset to do this but was unsuccessful.

To give a visual example of what I'd like to do:

```
New York
Paris
London
Berlin
```

And turn it into this:

```
New York
New York
New York
New York  
Paris
Paris
Paris
Paris
London
London
London
London
Berlin
Berlin
Berlin
Berlin
```

Any assistance with coming up with a non-VBA formula for this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW()/3,1))
```

[image]

Copy down to row 300, then copy the column and paste special > values to retain the values and get rid of the underlying formula.

Answer (score 0):

@teylyn, your answer works great - thanks!

I wanted to add titles in Row 1 so I used your formula but made a few adjustments. It works like a charm!

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$7,CEILING(ROW(A1)/4,1))
```

Thanks for turning me on to new functions. :)